# What am I doing wrong in this javascript loop operation?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, object

I've called some data from php using AJAX, and the result if I code alert(data.a) looks like this...

```
({a:[{my_id:"34", name:"Dave"}, {my_id:"39", name:"Barry"}]}
```

I'm not sure how to loop through this to extract the values.

My latest code...

```
for (var key in data.a)
{
 if (data.a.hasOwnProperty(key))
 {
   alert(key + " -> " + data.a[key]);
 }
}
```

... displays

```
0 -> [object Object]
```

and this displays the same too...

```
for (var i=0,  tot=data.a.length; i < tot; i++)
{
  for (var key in data.a[i]) 
  {
    if (data.a[i].hasOwnProperty(key))
    {
      alert(key + " -> " + data.a[i][key]);
    }
  }
}
```

What's the trick to looping through these results to extract the data for display?

If it helps, here's what I send at the end of my php...

```
$x['a'] = $myArray; 
echo json_encode($x);
```

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: `console.log(data.a);` and you will know the structure

Comment: Alerting for debugging purpose is not recommended. Alerting an object will print `[object ObjectName]`. Use `console.log`. Your second loop is right!

Comment: Not able to reproduce the problem. Please check this http://jsfiddle.net/5xnUS/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Wf8LU/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are doing `data.a[key]` in for loop, you are getting a json object: `{my_id:"34", name:"Dave"}` for key = 0, and `{my_id:"39", name:"Barry"}` for key = 1. So in order to get values you should do something like this:

```
for (var key in data.a)
{
  if (data.a.hasOwnProperty(key))
  {
     alert(key + " -> " + data.a[key].my_id);
     // data.a[key].name to get name attribute
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you after something like this?  Loop through all the objects the print out all of their properties and values?

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.a.length; i++) {
    var objectInArray = data.a[i];
    var keys = Object.keys(objectInArray);
    for (var j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
        var key = keys[j];
        alert(key  + " -> " + objectInArray[key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it just

```
for (var i=0; i < data.a.length; i++) {
  alert(data.a[i].my_id + " -> " + data.a[i].name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `data.a` is an array of objects, so this would work:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.a.length; i++) {
  console.log('my_id: ' + data.a[i].my_id);
  console.log('name: ' + data.a[i].name);
}
```